# Update Geany to use Nano shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, nano, geany

I use Geany a lot for editing, but ultimately use `nano` far more often. While navigating `nano` I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> key combo all the time (Cut/Paste). Yes, I understand there is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> but that will only work for text highlighted. Where as the aforementioned combo in `nano` will cut/paste entire lines.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> In Geany seems to remove the entire line, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> changes the indentation, not pasting the lines cut. How can I change this behavior, or is there an alternative keypress to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> which does the same thing?

Comment: My favourite IDE http://www.2buntu.com/?p=1455

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can changes keybinding in Geany from `edit`, `preferences`. The 2 you mention:

[image]

[image]

But you probably want this one:

[image]